# org-mode link to heading in other org-file

Tags: org-mode, emacs24.4

1. Is there a way to link to specific topic (*) in a different
   org-file?
2. How can I quickly find and copy the relative path from the
   current org-file to the file that I want to link to?

Probably both straight forward but I couldn't figure it out.
Thanks your help.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

For #2, first you'll want to add a couple of keybindings to your init file (these are the suggested keys in the Org manual) -

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c l") 'org-store-link)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-l") 'org-insert-link)
```

then you can hit `C-c l` somewhere in or on the item you want to link to, then `C-c C-l` where you want to place the link. It'll ask you to confirm the location and then enter a link name - you can just hit enter to accept the defaults. It will create a link like [[file:foo.org::*bar][link-name]], which displays as `link-name`.

See http://orgmode.org/manual/Handling-links.html for more details.

Comment: `C-c l` you mean in dired?

Comment: No, you hit `C-c l` in the org file you want to link to - it'll copy the link, then you can paste it with `C-c C-l`.

Comment: On `C-c l` I get an `is undefined ...` error.

Comment: Ah, sorry I forgot you need to create this binding yourself, though it's the standard - I'll amend the answer.

Comment: The OP asked about linked from one org file to another.  This solution works for me within a single file, but if I switch to another one `org-insert-link` doesn't show me the stored link.

Comment: @PaulBissex hmm, it works okay for me - it puts an absolute path to the originating file in the link.

Comment: What kind of path it uses depends on the value of `org-link-file-path-type`: check its value and doc string with `C-h v org-link-file-path-type`.

Answer (score 14):

1. you can reference this topic http://orgmode.org/manual/External-links.html#External-links

   file:projects.org::some words             text search in Org file

   file:projects.org::*task title            heading search in Org file
2. sorry, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
With number 2 I mean how can I easily get the path to the file that I want to link to paste it into the link.

Answer (score 2):

For 1, insert a link to a header (topic), inspired by @BrianBurns' answer, I found a more convenient solution:

1. Go to the header of org-file, that you want to link to, `M-x org-store-link`
   (`SPC n l`)
2. Go to the position, where you want to insert the link to the above mentioned
   header, `M-X org-insert-last-stored-link` (`SPC m l S`)

The bindings are from doom/emacs.

Comment: Also `C-c C-l` (`org-insert-link`) can be used for 2.